# Could someone explain me this classname *pointer1 = pointer1

Tags: c++, pointers

Hello guys while I studying the c++ I saw the code as follows

```
using namespace std;

class Point{
public:
    int x;
};

class testing{
public:
    void insert(int value){
        Point *newpoint = newpoint;
        newpoint ->x = value;
        cout << "newpoint val: " << (*newpoint).x <<endl;
    }
};

int main(){
    testing newlink;
    newlink.insert(40);
}
```

The point that I'm confusing now is this "Point *newpoint = newpoint;"

What's the purpose of an above code rather declare the object of the class Point and write as follows:

```
class Point{
    ~~
    }newpoint1;
    Point *newpoint = &newpoint1;
```

Sorry for asking a question like this which would be easy!
Any advice would be really helpful!

Comment: The definition `Point *newpoint = newpoint;` makes no sense and is useless. Even *undefined behavior* actually.

Comment: On a different note, instead of `(*newpoint).x` why not use the more common (and easier to read and write) `newpoint->x`? Especially considering that you do it on the line above. Consistency is very important for your code to be readable and maintainable.

Comment: Also note that since the pointer `newpoint` doesn't point anywhere valid, dereferencing the pointer (with `*` or with `->`) leads to *undefined behavior* as well. With `Point *newpoint = &newpoint1;` the pointer is pointing somewhere valid, but it will point to a single object, no matter how many times you call the `insert` function it will still be the one single `newpoint1` object that will be used and modified.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's actually supposed to say `Point *newpoint = new Point;`

Comment: The code will not compile (because the rvalue `newpoint` is not defined) and so it is not instructive.

Comment: @PhillipNgan No it will build, but likely crash when running. A statement like `Point *newpoint = newpoint;` is split into two parts: 1) Definition, which happens with the `Point *newpoint` part; And 2) Initialization which happens after the definition, with the ` = newpoint` part. So it's possible to initialize a variable with itself, but it just doesn't make sense and leads to UB.

Comment: *I saw the code as follows*  Where did you see this odd code?  You did not provide the context, but it seems to me that unless the context of the code is "bad C++ code", this is some bad code for several reason (already mentioned by others) — and not a good place to go for "studying C++".

Comment: Many thanks to u guys and I found that I was missing the new operator!! So yeah it was the new point, not the newpoint. Also, I read all the comments above and got many good tips from u guys! Thank you for the advices and comments!!

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, the pointer has been declared inside a class under the public section of class 'testing'. So, the pointer will be accessed or used only when that particular class is called by the object of class testing.

If we look at the snippet which you have provided below, in that case, 'newpoint1' would be considered as an object of class 'Point'. Hence, the pointer will be pointing at an object of class Point.

So this is the only difference between the two codes, that the pointer will be accessed by objects of different classes.